# Maven multimodule project and SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven

I have a problem related to subversion and a maven multimodule project in eclipse.

Right now my project structure is (ignore the errors =)):

[image]

Then I upload the parent directory to SVN and make a checkout in another location, thinking that the eclipse directory structure will maintain, but it didn't, and it's a pain in the back to work using folders.

So my question is: how can I upload my project to a svn repository and keep the structure of the picture above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid this by never creating project inside the eclipse workspace. Always put them somewhere else, and then check them into and out of svn.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I could do that, or I could import the inside projects in eclipse, and have the structure stay. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @bmargulies Have you tried doing this with m2e? I think that's one of the issues it's supposed to solve for you